# Default join type in lookup transformation?

Tags: lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

What is the default join type in the look up tranformation in informatica?

Whether it is inner join or left outer join? please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It's an outer join - if no matching row is found in the lookup table, you get an empty one back.

Answer (score 0):

It's Rigth outer join, every row from expression is passed forward whether a match is found or not(i.e Matching columns from lookup or NULL for Lookup columns).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers:
If you using some older versions of informatica Power Center (I think lower than 9.1), 
there is no multiple match feature to lookup, so unlike outer join, only one single value will be returned (or NULL when no match).

Answer (score 0):

The default join type of lookup transformation is left-outer join in informatica..considering your source is the left table..

Answer (score 0):

inner equijoin is the deafult join